# Two 3.3 V low signals to light bicolor LED

Tags: microcontroller, led, logic-level

I have a GPS receiver board that has two output pins to indicate the unit's status. I'd like to use these pins to illuminate a bicolor LED so that Status 1 will illuminate green, 2 will be yellow, and 3 will be red.

I am struggling to figure out how to use these signals as they are low logic-level outputs and only 4mA drive. I was thinking of using transistors
or solid state relays but haven't had any luck. Thanks in advance for any input.

[image]

Comment: Bicolor as in common anode/cathode or bicolor as in back-to-back?  What is the current handling capability of the output pins?  If it can handle the current of your LED, you could use a common anode bicolor LED with appropriate current limiting resistors.  Connect green to pin 1, red to pin 2, and you're done.

Comment: Find a common-anode LED (two LEDs in one package with the anodes tied together). Anode -> 3.3V. Cathode -> resistor -> pin (a different cathode for each pin).

Comment: Start by finding out the forward voltage of each LED to see if it is at all possible to drive them from 3.3V.

Answer (score 3):

Find a common-anode LED - two LEDs in one package with the anodes tied together.

Connect the anode to 3.3V.

Connect each cathode to a separate resistor and then one of the pins. Green cathode -> pin 1. Red cathode -> pin 2.

Comment: So the one piece I forgot to mention is that the pins are 4mA drive, so I assume I can't use the pins to directly power a LED?

Comment: @TravisW why haven't you updated your question with this new information?

Comment: @TravisW Just spec out a resistor for something like 3mA. If you want a bright LED, look for ultra high effeciency ones, which would be good indicators at 3mA

Comment: somehow I mixed up red and green - that is now fixed